# Inserting an array inside a MySQL table column

Tags: mysql

I just want to insert an array into a particular column inside the  mysql table. I don't have any idea if it is possible. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: refer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389299/inserting-an-array-into-a-mysql-database-column

Comment: You cannot store pure array but you will want to make it a string using json_encode and store it. eg json_encode($arr)

Comment: MySQL supports JSON datatype which can store JSON array (and in recent versions it can even index such array if the array data is integers).

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Optimal Way to Store/Retrieve Array in Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/761170/)", "[How to store an array into mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3413291/90527)", or possibly "[Insert array into database in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/185606/90527)". There are already many, many variants of this question on SO. Please read the site's help articles, especially on asking good questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting an array into a mysql database column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389299/inserting-an-array-into-a-mysql-database-column)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.